# How to smooth one part of a mesh?

Tags: mesh, objects

I am following an online tutorial by Blender Guru. I added in a new object (encircled in red below), which I originally applied smooth shading to

However, when I made this part of the overall mesh using CTRL + J, the  smooth shading disappeared. How do I make this particular part circled in red smooth shading, without affecting the rest of my mesh?

[image]

EDIT: Thank you I've done that, it's smoothed it a little however you can still see the lines, see below. Is there anyway to make it even smoother?

[image]

Comment: Make sure you press *Shade Smooth* under W menu, not just *Smooth*. If still using *Shade Smooth* doesn't help try either disabling Bevel modifier or setting it to *Angle* as now it bevels every edge in your mesh which might look like flat shading

Comment: Thank you, disabling the bevel modifier fixes it - however it disables the bevel for the whole mesh. How do I disable bevel for just this one part?

Comment: You don't need to disable modifier altogether, as I wrote above set Bevel modifier *Limit Method* option to *Angle* to avoid it beveling every edge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the faces ( if it's a loose part <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> ) > <kbd>spacebar</kbd> > shade smooth

edit:
In the latest blender defaults <kbd>F3</kbd>  is the search feature instead of <kbd>spacebar</kbd> .

Alternatively select an 
object > <kbd>w</kbd> > shade smooth

Comment: What do you mean "spacebar"? It just starts the animation.

Comment: @DamnVegetables Spacebar was originally the "search" function, in latest builds the default is to play animations. You can change this in the preferences. By default F3 is the search feature.

Answer (score 3):

In Edit mode select the mesh which you need to smooth. Press <kbd>W</kbd> and select shade smooth.

[image]

[image]